# Open Record from ACTIVE Sub Form if there are there are multiple sub forms on main form

Tags: vba, ms-access, subforms

I have a main form `[frmHome]`. It has two subforms `[sbfHome]` & `[sbfRemarkHome]`.

I would like a user to be able to click any field in any record on either form and open a new form with all of relevant data for that record.

I have tried `.ActiveControl` which did not work as is always FALSE.

I also I am trying to use `ActiveForm.Name` and carry that in the EOF/BOF portion of my code.

How can I know which sub form has focus?

```
 Private Sub btnSummary_Click()
 Dim frmCurrentForm As String
 frmCurrentForm = ActiveForm.Name

 If Not (Me.frmCurrentForm.Form.Recordset.EOF And 
 Me.frmCurrentForm.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
    With Me.frmCurrentForm.Form.Recordset
      txtEARNumber = .Fields("EAR Number")
    End With
 End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmView"
[Forms]![frmView].txtEARNumber = txtEARNumber
Forms!frmView.Form.Requery
Forms!frmView.Refresh
End Sub
```

or

```
 Private Sub btnSummary_Click()

 If Me.sbfHome.Form.ActiveControl = True Then

    If Not (Me.sbfHome.Form.Recordset.EOF And Me.sbfHome.Form.Recordset.BOF) 
    Then
        With Me.sbfHome.Form.Recordset
          txtEARNumber = .Fields("EAR Number")
        End With
    End If

Else

     If Not (Me.sbfRemarkHome.Form.Recordset.EOF And 
       Me.sbfRemarkHome.Form.Recordset.BOF) Then
       With Me.sbfRemarkHome.Form.Recordset
        txtEARNumber = .Fields("EAR")
       End With
     End If

End If

DoCmd.OpenForm "frmView"
[Forms]![frmView].txtEARNumber = txtEARNumber
Forms!frmView.Form.Requery
Forms!frmView.Refresh
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood your problem. I'd recommend using events to tell parent objects what action are done on a subform. This way focus, per se, doesn't matter, what matters is where an action took place. It also means there is a much looser coupling between the two objects.

In my example I made 3 forms: `Master`, `SubForm1` and `SubForm2`. I bound Both the subforms to a table with some mock data and made them `continuous forms`. The layout looks like this:

[image]

The code in each of the subforms is the same:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Event ButtonClicked(FormName As String, RecordId As Long)

Private Sub Command0_Click()
    RaiseEvent ButtonClicked(Me.Name, Me.ID)
End Sub
```

This says it will raise the `ButtonClicked` event whenever the Command0 button is clicked. You can customize those parameters in the event to whatever you want.

Then in the master form you can listen to the events as they happen like this:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents SubForm1 As Form_SubForm1
Private WithEvents SubForm2 As Form_SubForm2

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set SubForm1 = frmSubForm1.Form
    Set SubForm2 = frmSubForm2.Form
End Sub


Private Sub SubForm1_ButtonClicked(FormName As String, RecordId As Long)
    DoSomething FormName, RecordId
End Sub


Private Sub SubForm2_ButtonClicked(FormName As String, RecordId As Long)
    DoSomething FormName, RecordId
End Sub


Private Sub DoSomething(FormName As String, RecordId As Long)
    txtMessages = "Form Name: " & FormName & ", Record ID: " & RecordId
End Sub
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response I am still reviewing to see if I can modify this. Just want to note that my command button is on the main form and my subforms just simply have their Souce Object set to Query.qryXYZ and Query.qryABC So both queries only have a table (query result) and I only use the .field value from the selected record to run query's on a separate form.

Comment: I see, you want to filter the child forms. Have you tried `Link Master Fields`/`Link Child Fields` properties on the subforms? You can link those to columns in your data source or you can link to controls like a textbox.

Comment: Well no...not filter. The two queries are from different sources. the main form acts as search. I use a text box as a search to show all possible records that are *Like say "123".  Each query has "like" *txtboxvalue* criteria on various columns.The query's again are different sources and only related by the searched like value. I then want to run a search on anew form by using the .field value of the selected record from either query. they are different, but each has a common field, think of it as a task ID.